# I can easily double click my string grid and get the contents of a cell using a VCL application. How can I do this using FMX?

Tags: delphi, mouse, firemonkey

I use this code to be able to click on a certain cell in my grid and be able to output the string in that cell. It works perfectly fine in my VCL application.

```
procedure TForm1.StringGridBindSourceDB1CellDblClick(const Column: TColumn;
  const Row: Integer);


var
  Coordinates:TGridCoord;
  x:integer;
  Pt:TPoint;
  html_body:string;
  ClickCol:Integer;
  ClickRow:Integer;
begin
  Pt := grid.ScreenToClient(mouse.CursorPos);
  Coordinates := grid.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y);

  ClickCol := Coordinates.X;
  ClickRow := Coordinates.Y;
  html_body := grid.Cells[ClickCol, ClickRow];
end;
```

However when I try to achieve the same result in a firemonkey application I am not able to use "`TGridCood`," "`ScreenToClient`," or "`mouse.CursorPos`"

"`grid`" is a `TStringGrid`

Comment: Why not use the OnCellDblClick event? It delivers Column and Row.

Comment: I am doing that currently. I use the OnCellDblClickEvent and the code above is what I use. I'll update my question.

Comment: How do I proceed from there?

Comment: Just write html_body := grid.Cells[Column.Index, Row];